# How To Serve .json files from IIS7 when request is POST

Tags: asp.net, json, post, iis-7

I have an asp.net 4.0 web site that needs to serve files of type .json.  The request is coming in as a POST, which does not work.  GET works fine.  Anyone know what configuration I need to change to make this work?

Comment: Just a note that it's a best practice to redirect to a GET after accepting a POST: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: I'm mocking a server I can't control which means my javascript app needs to do the sam when going to my iis as it does to the production server which in this case is apache.  So, to not change the javascript and simulate the same behavior in IIS, I need the javascript to do a POST to get the results (not GET)

Comment: I'm not happy doing this as a handler, but I needed it done.  I posted my solution here:  http://peterkellner.net/2011/10/30/need-to-get-static-json-file-with-post-verb-on-iis-7-5/  I'd still like to know a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably already found the answer, but I think the problem lies in that you need to add a ".json" handler for your web server...

***By default IIS is not configured to handle .json extension.***

You can apply the mime type as a handler on the root of IIS so .json can be handled by every site or virtual folder in the IIS or just to the specific site.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Display properties for the IIS Server
3. Click MIME Types and then add the JSON extension:

   - File name extension: .json
   - MIME type: application/json
4. Go back to the properties for IIS Server
5. Click on Handler Mappings

   - Add a script map
   - Request path: *.json
   - Executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
   - Name: JSON

(***or Apache, if you're on the dev side...***)

[Apache Module mod_mime AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)

Note: In Ubuntu you ALSO need to edit the file /etc/mime.types and add the line:

```
application/json json
```

Then restart Apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -4):

GET or POST is irrelevant, its got nothing to do with the type of response your program sends.
There is no setting that would make a difference. Your problem is a logic error in your program.

Comment: Hi Logicus, there is no program here on the server side.  It's a static json file I'm trying to download.  when the client uses the GET verb it works, when the client uses the POST verb it fails with a 405.  I'd welcome other helpful suggestions.